# spree : theme installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I just set up spree successfully but want to add a new theme into it.
I chose that one :

https://github.com/dbwinger/spree_serenity_theme

But when I try a "bundle install", I get the following message :

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "spree_core":
In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
spree_core (= 3.0.4)
In Gemfile:
spree_core (= 3.0.4) ruby
spree_core (~> 3.0.0) ruby
spree_core (~> 3.0.0) ruby
spree_fancy (>= 0) ruby depends on
spree_core (~> 2.3.0.beta) ruby

Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, 
using only the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.
```

Any Idea to fix this issue ?

Ruby : 2.2.2p95

Rails : 4.2.2

Gemfile :

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.2.2'
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.18'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc


group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spring'
end


gem 'spree', '3.0.4'
gem 'spree_gateway', github: 'spree/spree_gateway', branch: '3-0-stable'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', github: 'spree/spree_auth_devise', branch: '3-0-stable'

gem 'spree_serenity_theme', :git => 'https://github.com/dbwinger/spree_serenity_theme.git'
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Have you tried running  `bundle update` as the prompt stated? Looking at the theme's dependency, it specifies `spree_core ~> 2.0.5`, and your current Gemfile.lock is at `3.0.4`.

Comment: Yes I did try `bundle update` and change  spree_core to 2.0.5 but nothing worked

Answer (score 0):

The Gem spree_serenity_theme is compatible with spree version 2 and not with spree version 3.
Check the dependencies of the gem https://github.com/dbwinger/spree_serenity_theme/blob/master/spree_serenity_theme.gemspec

That's why it is not working.

The current version of spree core is 3.0.4, You will have to install spree from 2-0 stable branch of the spree and not from the master branch.
https://github.com/spree/spree/tree/2-0-stable

You can create a fork of the theme and make changes according to your requirement for the latest version of spree

Thank you